# Is there a way to know when $(a+l_n)^n+(b+k_n)^n$ is an integer for integer $a$, $b$ and rational $l_n$, $k_n$ with $l_n+k_n=1$?

Tags: number-theory

Working with some sequences, I've gotten to something like this:

$$(a+l_n)^n+(b+k_n)^n \tag{1}$$

where $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ and $l_n,k_n\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1)$  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\backslash\{0,1\}$, such that $l_n+k_n=1$.

My first thought was that it cannot be integer never, but then I remembered the Fibonacci numbers where something with the sum of two irrational numbers that is natural. So,

> Is there a way to know when $(1)$ is an integer?

Any help please? Thanks in advance!

Edit: After doing some work on my problem, I got to:
$$l_n=\frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2^n} \qquad k_n=\frac{2^{n-1}+1}{2^n}$$
With this extra information, would this be helpful in order to find a solution?

Comment: My feeling, too, is that it can't be an integer, but I don't see how to prove it. I don't think the Fibonacci numbers will help. (By the way, $n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}$ is not enough. You need $n\ge 2$.)

Comment: Do you want solutions so that for one $n$ the above (for fixed $a,b$) is an integer, or do you want solutions so that for all $n$ the formula $(a+l_n)^n+(b+k_n)^n \tag{1}$ is integer? Also, do you want a procedure that for given $a,b$ tells you whether the formula is integer, or a theorem of the form " if $a,b$ fulfill <condition>, the formula is integer"?

Comment: @Sudix, I think the question is clear: can $(a+p)^n+(b+q)^n$ ever be an integer for integers $a,b$ and rationals $p,q\in(0,1)$ with $p+q=1$?

Comment: Kosarrara, I suggest you unaccept badjohn's answer. It really tells us nothing, and it discourages others from posting better answers.

Comment: @TonyK, yup, corrected, thanks

Comment: The question can be simplified by dropping the additive condition, a variable, and the suffixes: For which positive rational non-integer $r$ do there exist natural numbers $m>r$ and $n\geqslant2$ such that $r^n+(m-r)^n\in\Bbb N$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with a simple form:

$A=(a+\frac{c}{d})+(b+\frac{e}{d})$

It can be seen that if $d \big|c+e$ then A can be an integer. For example:

$(13+\frac{7}{15})+(17+\frac{8}{15})=\frac{465}{15}=31$

$(7+\frac{3}{5})+(3+\frac{2}{5})=\frac{465}{15}=15$

Where denominators of fraction are equal. We can make denominators equal in the case they are not equal. Let $l_n=\frac{c}{d}$ and $k_n=\frac{e}{f}$, then we may write:

$A=(a+\frac{c}{d})+(b+\frac{e}{f})=(a+\frac{c.f}{d.f})+(b+\frac{e.d}{f.d})$

Then the condition is:

$d.f\big|c.f+e.d$

For example we have:

$c=2$,$d=5$, $e=3$ and we want to find $f$ such that the condition is provided, we must have:

$ed+cf=15+2f=t(5f)$

The only solution is:

$t=1$, $15=5f-2f=3f$ ⇒ $f=5$

Now let $a=8$ and $b=11$ we have:

$(8+\frac{2}{5})+(11+\frac{3}{5})=\frac{100}{5}=20$

For general form $A=(a+\frac{c}{d})^n+(b+\frac{e}{f})^n$

n must be odd ,let $n=2t+1$,such that A can be reduced but the condition will be the same, i.e in following relation:

$A=(a+\frac{c}{d})^{2t+1}+(b+\frac{e}{d})^{2t+1}=\big[(a+\frac{c}{d})+(b+\frac{e}{f})\big]((a+\frac{c}{d})^{2t}(b+\frac{e}{f})+ . . . )$

if $(a+\frac{c}{d})+(b+\frac{e}{f})$ is integer, then A is integer and for that we must have:

$d.f\big|c.f+e.d$

c, d, e and f can be functions of n, for example $c=2^n$, $d=5^n$ etc.